# How to get current GPS location in NET Core 7.0 WinForms

Tags: c#, location

Is there any way to get current location on a .NET Core 7.0 Winforms application in order to print in a DevExpress Component map?

Many users of my application can work on movility and they need to open a form with a Devexpress map and point their location and see which customers are located around. So I need to get their laptop location. On .net framework there was the `GeoCoordinateWatcher` class but I do not see any equivalent class in .NET Core 7.

Answer (score -1):

Install the necessary NuGet package:

```
using System;
using System.Device.Location;

public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    private GeoCoordinateWatcher _watcher;

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher(GeoPositionAccuracy.Default);
        _watcher.PositionChanged += Watcher_PositionChanged;
        _watcher.Start();
    }

    private void Watcher_PositionChanged(object sender, GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate> e)
    {
        double latitude = e.Position.Location.Latitude;
        double longitude = e.Position.Location.Longitude;

        // Do something with the latitude and longitude values (e.g., display them in TextBoxes)
        textBoxLatitude.Text = latitude.ToString();
        textBoxLongitude.Text = longitude.ToString();
    }
}
```

Modified according to your logic

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: As i said in main post, GeoCoordinateWatcher is NOT available in NET CORE 7